# Pipe not clearing - I'm reading the same first character every time

Tags: c, process, pipe

I'm currently reading a pipe from a child process as follows. The problem is that while the fgetc is working, it's not starting a new line. It's continuously reading so my program always breaks at '!'

E.g:
! -> !example -> !exampleExample
instead of
! -> example -> Example

Below is my read function, but the pipe is basically not clearing when read.

```
char* read_line(FILE* file) {
    char* result = malloc(sizeof(char) * 80);
    int position = 0;
    int next = 0;
    while (1) {
        next = fgetc(file);
        if (next == '!') {
                return "!";
        }
        if (next == EOF || next == '\n') {
            result[position] = '\0';
            return result;
        } else {
            result[position++] = (char)next;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: btw the cast `(char)next` is useless

Comment: Returning either a pointer to a string literal or a pointer to allocated memory guarantees that memory will be leaked (or undefined behavior executed).

Comment: In any case, a [mcve] is needed here. Minimally prove that you're **printing** the `read_line`. Also the sending routine in the child process is of interest.

Comment: this is a very bad coding. Even for example code ! Hope no one else will geared on this...Maybe you should read more Books about Programming in C !

Comment: regarding: `char* result = malloc(sizeof(char) * 80);`  1) when calling any of the memory allocation functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the expression `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has not effect.  Suggest removing that expression.

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, need to post code that cleanly compiles, so we can debug the problem.  The posted code is just a snippet.  Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of crash as there is no limit over the access result[position]. The memset is not done after malloc. Ignoring all these the issue seems to be in the function calling the read_line. Check on the handling of the returned address , as return "!" is not correct.